# Compare the slopes and intercepts between 2 variables in SPSS

Tags: regression, spss

There are 4 groups, each one having two 2 variables, X and Y. I am trying to understand the regression between them. For X variable I have 2 categories, positive and negative. I am not understanding how to compare the slopes and intercepts between X (positive and negative) and Y. Do I have to invert the negative values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Say X represents whether or not someone is female (the alternative being male), such that the value 1 represents women and the value 0 men, and Y represents hourly wage. If you were to run a regression with Y as the dependent/explained/left-hand-side variable and X as the independent/explanatory/right-hand-side variable, then you will get two numbers: the constant and slope. The constant is just the mean wage for men, and the slope is the difference in mean wage between men and women.

This is all the information you can extract from a regression with these two variables. So I am uncertain with what slopes you want to compare, as there is only one slope. Similarly, there is only one constant, so again there is nothing to compare.

Comment: Thank you. I have not mentioned that there are 4 groups, each one having these 2 variables, X and Y.

Comment: Please edit your question to make that clear